# AngularJs scope undefined while binding a textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-bindings

Trying to bind data to input control from scope using below code.

```
var app = angular.module('ng_app', []);

app.controller("ITEM_Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var PlantId = "abcFC"; $scope.mdItemId; $scope.mdFlavorId; $scope.itemDtls = {};
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:12752/api/Item/GetItem',
        params: { Plant_Id: PlantId, Item_Id: '1234567' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        debugger;
        //  $scope.itemDtls = {};   
alert(response.data);  --> in alert msg as  [object Object]            
    //    $scope.itemDtls = response.data; -->  ReferenceError: itemDtls is not defined
      //  $scope.testmdItemId = itemDtls.ITEM_ID;
        //  $scope.itemDtls =   response.data;
     //   $scope.mdItemId = response.data.ITEM_ID;  --> scope mdItemId undefined
       // $scope.mdItemId = JSON.parse(response.data.ITEM_ID);
       // $scope.mdFlavorId = JSON.parse(response.data.FLAVOR_ID);
      //.mdFlavorId = "test data";  -- > binding successfully
        $scope.itemDtls = response.data;
            $scope.mdItemId = itemDtls.ITEM_ID;
            $scope.mdFlavorId = response.data.FLAVOR_ID;    
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
});
```

Tried in different ways to bind to input control as above but getting msg as scope undefined.

```
<body ng-app="ng_app">
    <table ng-controller="ITEM_Ctrl">
        <tr>              
            <td>
                <div>                   
                    <input type="text" id="itemid"  ng-model="mdItemId" />
                </div>
                <div>                 
                    <input type="text" id="flavorid"  ng-value="mdFlavorId" />
                </div>                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you sure your success handler is being called?

Comment: Yes able to get debugger and alert msg.

Comment: You probably need to define your variables outside of the AJAX request, and then you can update them in the success handler. My guess is when the template is loading, those variables don't exist.

Comment: Updated outside ajax req but still same issue exists.

Comment: Try defining your variables with an extra level, something like `$scope.This_Controller.mdItemId` and `$scope.This_Controller.mdFlavorId`, and then refer to them within the page as `This_Controller.mdItemId` and `This_Controller.mdFlavorId`. Cannot explain why, but this solved a similar problem I had in the past. Also, as suggested by @AndroidNoobie, you should defined them at the controller's level and not inside any function contained there.

Comment: updated like below and getting error msg as Cannot read property 'mdItemId' of undefined
 IM_Mod_app.controller("IM_Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            var PlantId = "DFC"; $scope.IM_Ctrl.mdItemId; $scope.IM_Ctrl.mdFlavorId; $scope.itemDtls = {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
 var itemDtls  = response.data;
 $scope.mdItemId = itemDtls [0].ITEM_ID;
```